# How can I customize my new created projects as default new project in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to have an older version of Xcode in my mac the old version of Xcode 12, Xcode 12 keeps showing Canvas selected even if I delete the preview codes for canvas, which in updated Xcode versions, Xcode removes check mark for Canvas as soon as we delete the code for preview part, So I need to know if I can changes the setting of Xcode 12 in some where that it creates a projects without having Canvas checked, or making Xcode uncheck Canvas as soon as I delete the preview code, currently it is bothering me, that I have to manually or with shortcut key uncheck it. Is there a way for it?

[image]

Comment: I do not know the specifics for XCode, but you can try creating a new project, setting it up the way you want and make a git repo from it. On new projects, clone that repo instead of creating a new project.

Comment: Sounds somehow weird... I don't remember such bug in Xcode 12. What happens if "Show Editor Only" selected, or "Assistant"? It should be just that - change selection.

Comment: @Asperi: It solves the issue, but again I have to go and hit "Show Editor only", but I do not want do that, for example if you delete preview code for Xcode 13.0+ it shows just codes without showing canvas automatically.

Comment: @tutiplain: I just tried your given way, it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even without a git you can simply copy the whole project folder and rename the project

Comment: It is not about copy and paste, even if I close the original project and open it again, it will shows Canvas even if I have no preview code, Have you tried your way before answering?